# Objective-c syntax error deleting Firebase tokens in ios

Tags: objective-c, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have zero experience with objective c and having problem writing a simple method. I can compile fine without the code below, so I'm guessing is just a syntax error.

I am trying to use this function [deleteIDWithHandler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseinstanceid/api/reference/Classes/FIRInstanceID)

```
#firebase.h
- (void)deleteInstanceId:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;


#Firebase.m

- (void)deleteInstanceId:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
  CDVPluginResult *pluginResult;

  FIRInstanceIDDeleteHandler handler = ^void(NSError *error){
if (error) {
  NSLog(@"Unable to delete instance.");
 } else {
  NSLog(@"Instance Deleted");
 }
}

  pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] deleteIDWithHandler:handler]];

  [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that I was trying to attach the result of the handler which is  (void) in the param messageAsString which takes a string. For some reason, the compiler would not give me a trace stack until I fixed this which ended up showing up more syntax errors. If anyone is trying to delete all firebase tokens in a Cordova app, the code below should do it.

```
- (void)deleteInstanceId:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
  [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] deleteIDWithHandler:^void(NSError *_Nullable error){
    if (error) {
      NSLog(@"Unable to delete instance");
    } else {
      CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
      [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }
  }];
}
```